# How can I fix my modal to work using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I decide to make a modal for my homepage using Vanilla JavaScript. I have looked at several examples on how to build a modal from scratch but I'm stuck at getting the display property to change using my JavaScript code.

```js
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("ex");

var modal = document.getElementsByClassName("vid-modal")

function clearModal() {
  modal.style.display == "none";
}

function windowOnClick(event) {
  if (event.target === span) {
    clearModal();
  }
}

function fireWhenReady(func) {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', func)
}

fireWhenReady(windowOnClick);
```

```css
.vid-modal {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  width: 1000px;
  height: 500px;
  top: 250px;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 1002;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  /* display: initial; */
  /* aug 21 still working on modal display */
  display: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="vid-modal">
  <span class="vexit"><i class="fa fa-window-close ex" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
  <div class="vid-box">
    <iframe id="front-video" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/Hua4MRTKmy0?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0;autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

I expect to set the display property to "none", and apply more advanced solutions to this code.

Comment: `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', func)` adds a listener for the event that your document is loaded and fires the function. So your function fires once when the DOM is loaded and doesn't do anything since event.target isn't the span element. It doesn't add an event listener for the 'click' event.

Comment: Sorry, I just edited you're question as it causes the confusion as having two snippets.